# column_spec in R's kable does not change columns possibly due to headers

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I want to reduce the width of my columns for my latex-rmarkdown pdf output but it doesn't seem to work.

**desired output**

[image: desired output]

---

`column_spec()` is unable to adjust the width of the headers and they are not able to wrap.

```
kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down", full_width = F) |> 
  column_spec(2:8, width = "5em") |>
```

**My Output**

[image: My output]

Comment: You need to provide a minimal working example to create that output. You may show the data frame or codes so that we can tell how you implemented the header row to grouped columns (i.e. `DEPENDENT VARIABLE Civil Conflict 1,000 Deaths`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a header for group columns via [`kableExtra::add_header_above()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf#page=17). When you insert such a header into a table, you can specify the width of that header by using a LaTeX command `\parbox{..width..}{..contnets..}`. To use any LaTeX command in a table created using `knitr::kable()` and `kableExtra`'s  functions, you have to set [`escape = FALSE`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html#escape-special-characters) in these functions.

[image]

```
mtcars |>
  head() |>
  knitr::kable(
    "latex",
    booktabs = TRUE
  ) |>
  kable_styling(
    latex_options = "scale_down",
    full_width = FALSE
  ) |>
  column_spec(
    1:2,
    width = "5em"
  ) |>
  add_header_above(
    c(
      " ",
      "\\\\parbox{5em}{this header for group columns is way too long and I want to wrap this but I don't know how}" = 5,
      "Group 2" = 6
    ),
    escape = FALSE
  )
```

Comment: @user I think you can accept and up-vote any answer to your questions! If you think the answer is helpful, you can accept and/or up-vote it!